# Is there any way to add an extension property into a List<CustomDto> in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Could anyone advcie a kotlin-style way of adding an extension property for a list of certain type? For example - i have a custom list of

```
// i can't modify that dto straight, only using kotlin extensions
data class CustomList(
    val items: List<CustomDto>
)  

data class CustomDto(
    val isUsed: Boolean,
    val items: List<Long>
)
```

And i have a list of:

```
val myList = CustomList(items = listOf(
    CustomDto(isUsed = true, items = listOf(1L, 2L, 3L)),
    CustomDto(isUsed = true, items = listOf(4L, 5L, 6L)),
    CustomDto(isUsed = false, items = listOf(7L, 8L, 9L))
))
```

I need to add an extension property "count" that handles some operations to list of CustomDto items that isUsed=true... Something like this:

```
val count: Long get() = items.filter { it.isUsed }.flatMap { it.items }.count { it > 3 }
```

so i could get such a json:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "isUsed" = true, "items": [1, 2, 3] },
        { "isUsed" = true, "items": [4, 5, 6] },
        { "isUsed" = true, "items": [7, 8, 9] }
    ],
    "count": 3
}
```

How should i add an extension property for in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an extension function to your `data class CustomList` you have to write a `fun` that uses the `this` operator of `CustomList`. You can achieve that by adding the following `fun` to your code:

```kotlin
fun CustomList.count(): Int {
    return this.items.filter { it.isUsed }
                        .flatMap { it.items }
                        .count { it > 3 }
}
```

The output of

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myList = CustomList(
        items = listOf(
            CustomDto(isUsed = true, items = listOf(1L, 2L, 3L)),
            CustomDto(isUsed = true, items = listOf(4L, 5L, 6L)),
            CustomDto(isUsed = false, items = listOf(7L, 8L, 9L))
        )
    )
    println("Items > 3 of items in use: ${myList.count()} ones...")
}
```

is then

```
Items > 3 of items in use: 3 ones...
```

If you need an extension property `count`, then you can add an extension property that uses the extension function above, like this:

```kotlin
val CustomList.count: Int
    get() = this.count()
```

and alter the `fun main()` as follows

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myList = CustomList(
        items = listOf(
            CustomDto(isUsed = true, items = listOf(1L, 2L, 3L)),
            CustomDto(isUsed = true, items = listOf(4L, 5L, 6L)),
            CustomDto(isUsed = false, items = listOf(7L, 8L, 9L))
        )
    )
    // now this uses the extension property
    println("Items > 3 of items in use: ${myList.count} ones...")
}
```

to get the same output

```
Items > 3 of items in use: 3 ones...
```

So, basically, your example idea was pretty near to what you could use, just make

```kotlin
val count: Long
    get() = items.filter { it.isUsed }.flatMap { it.items }.count { it > 3 }
```

be

```kotlin
val CustomList.count: Int
    get() = items.filter { it.isUsed }.flatMap { it.items }.count { it > 3 }
```

Comment: but i need an extension property... not a function

Comment: @bajiepka13 yes, just realized... coming soon

Comment: @bajiepka13 now there's an extension property that uses the extension function defined before. You can alter the example to just having an extension property, if necessary.